# Not able to join 2 tables in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring-data-jpa. I am working on a task management system.
I have 2 entities:

```
public class Task {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long taskId;
private String title;
private String description;
private Status status;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "userId")
private User assignee;
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userId;
private String name;
private String email;
private Active active;
private String password;
```

}

I have an endpoint that creates a new task:

```
    @PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public TaskResponse addTask(@Valid @RequestBody Task task){
    return taskService.addTask(task);
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
    @Override
public TaskResponse addTask(Task task) {
    taskRepository.save(task);
    return mapToTaskResponse(task);
}
```

The error I get when I send a request is:

```
2023-01-24 15:10:01.825  WARN 1961 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.tasksmanagement.entity.User` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.tasksmanagement.entity.User` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 5, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.tasksmanagement.entity.Task["assignee"])]
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Basically I create a user and send the id of this user in the request (the assignee field in the payload - screenshot attached) in order to assign the new task to that user.
Can anyone please assist and help me understand what is the issue with the request?
Should I send something else instead of the userId?

Thank you
[image: screenshot]

Comment: is `Task` a `TaskRequest` ????

Comment: no. i edited the question with the correct method

Answer (score 1):

`assignee` is of type `User` not `Integer`, and yet you are sending `assignee:1` which fails the deserialization of your request.

it should be rather

`assignee:{ userId:1 }`

but it will fail anyway on later on during atempt to persist the `Task` (but that is a different issue)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to create a `Task` for a `User` who has an `id` of 1.

All you need to do is map you `User` object with your `Task` object.

Try the following

```
@Override
public TaskResponse addTask(Task task) {
    User assignee = new User();
    assignee.setUserId(task.assignee);

    task.setAssignee(assignee);

    taskRepository.save(task);
    return mapToTaskResponse(task);
}
```